# Iceberg metadata folder size growing in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, apache-iceberg

Table have small inserts but we are looking options to let not grow of metadata folder in S3 for Athena Iceberg table. Tried with config values of`optimize_rewrite_delete_file_threshold = 1` and `vacuum_max_snapshot_age_seconds=60` .

Running both `OPTIMIZE & VACUUM` commands but metadata folder size is not reducing.

Also, not able to set property `write_max_metadata_files_to_keep` to Athena table . But , AWS documentation says it will reduce the size of metadata folder but can't set this property to table and it is failing with error `unsupported table property key`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `expire_snapshots` which will remove old data files as well as metadata files i.e. `metadata.json`, `manifest_list.avro` and `manifest.avro`.

```
CALL hive_prod.system.expire_snapshots('db.sample', TIMESTAMP '2021-06-30 00:00:00.000', 100);
```

[Iceberg documentation for spark procedure](https://CALL%20hive_prod.system.expire_snapshots(%27db.sample%27,%20TIMESTAMP%20%272021-06-30%2000:00:00.000%27,%20100);)

Also, you can consider merging smaller manifest file with [rewrite_manifests](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-procedures/#rewrite_manifests)